# Как вытащить определенные свойства файла?

Tags: python, файлы, ос

Каким образом можно получить определенные(имя, количество страниц, размер в кб, дата изменения файла) свойства(атрибуты) файла(pdf) с помощью модуля os или другого модуля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот код для нахождения даты и времени создания файла

```
 import os
 import datetime
 def modification_date(filename):
      t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
      return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
```